# Tree Database Design in Django for Organisation Feature

Tags: django, database, django-models

I want to implement an organisation feature in django 1.8.
 - Organisation has multiple teams belonging to it.
 - Any team can have multiple team below/under it.
I started with this core, but I don't know is this the good way to design model structure.

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    logo = models.ImageField()


class Team(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class ParentTeam(models.Model)
    parent_team = models.OneToOneField(Team, null=True, blank=True)
    child_team  = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
```

Am I doing right or there should be other way to design? 
Thanks,

Comment: When you have parent_team as null=True blank=True whats the point of having it? This way you will allow a ParentTeam instance to be created without parent_team and one or many child_team. I dont think you want that.

Comment: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can club Team and ParentTeam model into one as

```
class Team(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    child_teams = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='children')
```

Its something I would have done with it.